# Highcharts column only show one category

Tags: javascript, mysql, highcharts

I make a chart using Highchart with column type. I working with database mysql

```
series: [<?php while ($c1=mysql_fetch_array($qc1)){ ?>
            {
                name: '<?php echo $c1[0]; ?>',
                data: [<?php echo $c1[1]; ?>]
            },
            <?php } ?>
            ]
```

I want to numbering xAxes from 1-11

```
xAxis: {
                categories: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11']
            },
```

But it only show 1.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by creating multiple series, so there are two options:

1) Create one series instead:

```
series: [
    data: [<?php while ($c1=mysql_fetch_array($qc1)){ ?>
        {
            name: '<?php echo $c1[0]; ?>',
            y: [<?php echo $c1[1]; ?>]
        },
        <?php } ?>
        ]
 }
```

2) Or for each of the points set `x`:

```
series: [
        <?php 
            $index = 0; 
            while ($c1=mysql_fetch_array($qc1)){ 
              $index++; 
        ?>
              {
                name: '<?php echo $c1[0]; ?>',
                data: [<?php echo $index.','.$c1[1]; ?>]
              },
        <?php 
          } 
        ?>
        ]
```

Note: Second solution may require to set `plotOptions.series.grouping = false`. Otherwise Highcharts will make space in each category for all of the series.

Comment: I'm not a PHP guy, maybe I made a mistake in the code. Please, check if code compiles properly. If code works, then provide javascript errors. I hope you get the idea how it suppose to work?